# NextAuth: Authorize calls to the Twitter API using OAuth

Tags: node.js, twitter, oauth, next.js, next-auth

I'm having trouble understanding how the Twitter authorization system works. I'm using [next-auth](https://next-auth.js.org) to authenticate with Twitter and I get back a response that looks like:

```
account: {
    provider: 'twitter',
    type: 'oauth',
    id: 12345,
    refreshToken: '12345OdWwHk85yESQCNkRrqkLUIQ78SCKh4Ry',
    accessToken: '20744357-12345eJhOMjEEuuMARXF6DS7fZKqcyIULw',
    accessTokenExpires: null
  }
```

How can I use that to make calls against the Twitter API?

Using `twitter-lite`, how can I use the `refreshToken` and `accessToken` to authorize requests? It seems that I need `access_token_key` and `access_token_secret`.

Any help would be forever appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow their documentation to sign your requests with the access tokens u have which is provided over here. I’m guessing you are working with OAuth 2.0 which gives you limited access to Twitter API.

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/overview

The token you have posted seems like a bearer token ( OAuth 2.0). It won’t work with the API you are trying to use. https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/oauth-2-0/application-only , you need to check with next-auth if they support Twitter OAuth 1.0. I will research next-auth too

Comment: It seems that `next-auth` already is using OAuth 1.0-a: https://github.com/iaincollins/next-auth/blob/9a630dcb01fe8785f2aea023fc4aea05577fd328/src/providers/twitter.js

Comment: Use the value present in refresh_token itself. NextAuth incorrectly refers to this as refreshToken instead of accessTokenSecret.

Answer (score 3):

NextAuth incorrectly refers to `access_token_secret` as `refreshToken`. Use the value present in `refreshToken`. I tested this with Twitter Provider and it works.

Have raised an issue with nextauth https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/1321